# Is there a more ruby way of doing this logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my controller index action

```
sub1 = "(select sum(courses_users.know) from courses_users where courses_users.course_id = courses.id) know_score"
sub2 = "(select levels.name from levels where levels.id = courses.level_id) level_name"
@courses = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "select name,#{sub1},#{sub2} from courses order by level_id, know_score"
@total_score = User.count() * 2;
```

this is the view logic

```
<% level_name = "" %>
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
<% if course[2] != level_name %>
  <tr>
      <th colspan='2' style='text-align:left;'><br /><br /><%= course[2] %><br /><br /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Knowledge Score</th>
  </tr>
  <% level_name = course[2] %>
<% end %>
<tr>
  <td><%= course[0] %></td>
  <td><%= (course[1].nil? ? 0 : course[1].to_i) %>/<%= @total_score %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

this is an example of what each couse looks like in the loop

```
["PHP - The Basics", #<BigDecimal:1033708d0,'0.31E2',9(18)>, "Beginner"]----------------
```

this seems like such a hack and i would love to make this more ruby like

here is my db structure if that will help

```
create_table "courses", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "target_id"
  t.integer  "level_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "order_num"
end

create_table "levels", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is add two scopes to get the related counts from the courses table:

```
class Course
  has_many :courses_users
  belongs_to :level

  scope :with_know_score, joins(:courses_users).group("courses.id").select(["courses.*"," sum(courses_users.know) as know_score"])
  scope :with_level_name, joins(:level).select(["courses.*","levels.name as level_name"])
end
```

You can then simplify your controller code:

```
@courses = Course.with_know_score.with_level_name
@total_score = User.count * 2
```

And your view code:

```
<% level_name = "" %>
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <% if course.level_name != level_name %>
    ...
    <% level_name = course.level_name %>
  <% end %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= course.name %></td>
    <td>
      <%= course.know_score || 0 %>/<%= @total_score %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

In the console you should be able to type:

```
c = Course.with_know_score.with_level_name.first
c.name # 'PHP ...'
c.level_name # 'Beginner'
c.know_score #
```

Comment: seems great but its failing on missing attribute: name...i think its not giving me the object data or something

Comment: I updated my scopes so that you can get the course name as well.

Comment: I appreciate all the help ..thanks again but one last issue  undefined method `know_score' for #<Course:0x103490dc8>

Comment: I am not able to replicate this issue. Make sure your scopes are typed correctly. You should be able to do the following in the console: c=Course.with_know_score.with_level_name.first and then you should be able to access c.name, c.know_score and c.level_name. P.S: I also updated the scopes to make the generated SQL cleaner.

Comment: ok so i have this c.first
 => #<Course id: 70, name: "Timesheets", target_id: 1, level_id: 1, created_at: "2011-01-17 18:46:43", updated_at: "2011-02-07 17:18:17", order_num: 1>

Comment: and when i do  c.know_score
NoMethodError: undefined method `know_score' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x10377e300>

Comment: Okay, if c.first is that object then you should be able to call c.first.name, c.first.know_score and c.first.level_name to get the different attributes.

Comment: c.first.know_score
NoMethodError: undefined method `know_score' for #<Course:0x103729f80>

Comment: If c.first is the course object then you'll have to do c.first.know_score. I suggested doing "c=Course.with_know_score.with_level_name.first" that would set c to the object. I'll add this to my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: looking at the Course object and i dont see know_score

Comment: c=Course.with_know_score.with_level_name.first
 => #<Course id: 70, name: "Timesheets", target_id: 1, level_id: 1, created_at: "2011-01-17 18:46:43", updated_at: "2011-02-07 17:18:17", order_num: 1> 
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :013 > c.know_score
NoMethodError: undefined method `know_score' for #<Course:0x1036406a0>
maybe i am crazy or something

Comment: If you can't do this in the console then your setup is not correct. I have verified that the console code works. Make sure you have setup your scopes and relations properly and that you are making the right calls in the console.

Comment: i must be doing something wrong because i tried this  c=Course.with_know_score.first
 => #<Course id: 70, name: "Timesheets", target_id: 1, level_id: 1, created_at: "2011-01-17 18:46:43", updated_at: "2011-02-07 17:18:17", order_num: 1>  c.know_score
NoMethodError: undefined method `know_score' for #<Course:0x1033d3778>
thats with only the with_know_score

Comment: I might be able to help you debug the issue. Can you post the SQL that this generates: Course.with_know_score.with_level_name.to_sql

Comment: Course.with_know_score.with_level_name.to_sql
 => "SELECT     courses.*, levels.name as level_name FROM       `courses`  INNER JOIN `courses_users` ON `courses_users`.`course_id` = `courses`.`id` INNER JOIN `levels` ON `levels`.`id` = `courses`.`level_id` ORDER BY  level_id, order_num"

Comment: The problem is you don't have the with_know_score scope setup properly. I get the following: "SELECT courses.*, sum(courses_users.know) as know_score, levels.name as level_name FROM courses INNER JOIN courses_users ON courses_users.course_id = courses.id INNER JOIN levels ON levels.id = courses.level_id GROUP BY courses.id". The good news is that the with_level_name scope is setup properly.

Comment: Verify that the scope and your relations are properly setup and that you can make calls like Course.courses_users for example.

Comment: Course.courses_users
NoMethodError: undefined method `courses_users' for #<Class:0x1035d2600>

Comment: usually relationships if there is has_many u need the instance like c.courses_users and not Course.courses_users

Comment: Right, just mistyped it in my comment. I don't know what to tell you Matt except that you are missing something in your setup. I have replicated this code in a test Rails app with the database tables and all and it works. All I know is that your with_know_score scope is incorrect. Try to get that scope working and you should be on your way.

Comment: Course.with_know_score.to_sql
 => "SELECT     courses.*,  sum(courses_users.know) as know_score FROM       `courses`  INNER JOIN `courses_users` ON `courses_users`.`course_id` = `courses`.`id` GROUP BY  courses.id ORDER BY  level_id, order_num" 
Course.with_know_score.with_level_name.to_sql
 => "SELECT     courses.*, levels.name as level_name FROM       `courses`  INNER JOIN `courses_users` ON `courses_users`.`course_id` = `courses`.`id` INNER JOIN `levels` ON `levels`.`id` = `courses`.`level_id` GROUP BY  courses.id ORDER BY  level_id, order_num"

Comment: so it seems that if i append the named_scopes that the second sum fails

Comment: It seems to me like something is getting mixed up and you are losing your select statement. I would check that you are using the latest version of Rails and that you are using arrays in your select statements instead of just strings.

Comment: got it with this    scope :with_know_score, joins(:courses_users, :level).group("courses.id").select(["courses.*"," sum(courses_users.know) as know_score, levels.name as level_name"])

Comment: Why are you also joining on :level? If you aren't using the scopes I posted in the example then I can't tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I just added both in one query to make it more consise....thanks again for all your help